# "Keeping up with the car dash icons" - What's the pun?

Tags: british-english, puns

[This tweet](https://slack-redir.net/link?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Falistairj90%2Fstatus%2F761113787604701184&v=3) asserts that an article by this title contains a pun. However, myself and a few friends, all American, don't get the joke. We assume it's in the title:

> Keeping up with the car dash icons

This isn't guaranteed, of course. The header above the title reads:

> Take our warning quiz

And the text below reads:

> The AA has revealed its crews attend 17,000 call-outs every month from drivers mystified by dashboard warning lights. But how many do you recognize?

followed by a note about the author and the quiz answers.

The [AA](https://www.theaa.com/breakdown-cover/) appears to be a British roadside service, similar to the American [AAA](http://www.aaa.com/). So I assume this is an article in a British publication. Is there some British usage we're not aware of?

Comment: http://www.eonline.com/now/keeping-up-with-the-kardashians

Comment: Hint - Think Kim, Kourtney, and Khloe.

Comment: Should have spelled it, **ikons**

Comment: It's to your unending credit that you didn't get the pun. And as an added bonus, you don't have to find better friends.

Comment: What are "form drivers"?

Comment: @HotLicks They're victims of disfiguring typos. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pun refers to the American reality TV show, *Keeping Up with the Kardashians*, starring the remaining family of Robert Kardashian. While Robert Kardashian was famous for defending OJ Simpson in the infamous double murder trial, the rest of the Kardashian clan is famous mostly by proxy.

That title itself is a play on the phrase "Keeping up with the Joneses" which refers to trying to keep up with your neighbors or peers in terms of material wealth. Meanwhile, Keeping up with car dash icons, is what it seems like, which is making sense of all the myriad indicator lights in a car.